# Rygel 0.38.3 drops cabeled connection after 30 minutes

Tags: server, ethernet, media, rygel

I installed rygel and it starts upp fine and shows on my TV as it should.

Choosing a video (any playable type) runs fine for about 30 minutes or so and then the connection are dropped and the share don't show on the dlna screen.

All dir show up on the TV screen fine as well as the files. I can start a video file and it runs fine for 30 minutes then it aborts and the ubuntu server drops connection to the TV. Restarting the TV the server shows again and plays for 30 minutes and drops and vanish from the tv screen. its NOT the TV, it works fine using a laptop with minidlna or via the routers media server. just not with ubuntus rygel setup. is there a built in 30 minutes limit in rygel ? or something I have to xhange in the setup ?

No .cfg files are touched yet in a fresh ubuntu 20.04 LTS install and TV and computer are connected via Ethernet cable. The part of Ubuntu that I   have a problem with are "Rygel" media solution.
Rygel try to connect to IP 239.255.255.250 a number of times and after about 40 tries it start a cron timer and drops the connection between computer and TV set. Is there a way to stop "Rygel" from sending info to that IP ? or NOT start the countdown cron timer ?

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu? Which version? Have you read `man rygel`? Just after it drops, `sudo journalctl --since="-5 minutes"` might show some interesting log info.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS in a fresh install (no .cfg files altered yet)

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS in a fresh install (no .cfg files altered yet) I had a look at rygels homepage and the manual but I can not find anything that would affect the time a video plays. The only "time limit" i find in the cfg file are the show picture.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.